# Javascript - how to have a alert on non-200 response from fetch?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have some code like

```
fetch(url).then().catch
```

How do I make the window show an alert if the response wasn't 200? Because with then and catch they are in their own context so I can't do the usual "window.alert"

Answer (score 1):

> Because with then and catch they are in their own context so I can't do the usual "window.alert"

Sure you can.

> alert on non-200 response from fetch?

Are you sure that's what you want?  There are other `2xx` status codes that are considered just fine.

Try something like this...

```
fetch(url).then((res) => {
  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error('Response not OK', res);
  }
  return res;
}).then(/* your then handler */).catch((e) => {
  alert('There was an error!!');
});
```

See also:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/ok